# how to append 10 <p> that i have created with for loop into parent?

Tags: javascript, html

I have created 10 `<a>` tags with a `for` loop.
how to append all 10

into a parent all in one?

```
    for (i = 0; i < h2Len; i++){
        document.createElement("a");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.appendChild` for this purpose.

```
for (i = 0; i < h2Len; i++){
   const a = document.createElement("a");
   //set some properties...
   parentElement.appendChild(a);
}
```

```js
const parentElement = document.querySelector('div');
for(let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  const a = document.createElement('a');
  a.href = "https://example.com";
  a.textContent = "Link " + i;
  a.style.display = "block";
  parentElement.appendChild(a);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: it's works, but i did that before with var instead of  const and it dose't work, do you know why?

Comment: @AhmadAdel Could you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: for (j = 0; j < 10; j++){
    var cree = document.createElement("a");
    var ss = document.getElementsById("go-box");
    ss.appenChild(cree);

}

Comment: @AhmadAdel It should be `document.getElementById`.

Comment: @AhmadAdel No problem. (My username is spelled "hev1".)

Answer (score 2):

To avoid reflows every time you are appending a child to the parent element, you can use [document fragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment)

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

for (i = 0; i < h2Len; i++){
   const newElement = document.createElement("a");
   fragment.appendChild(newElement);
}

parentElement.appendchild(fragment);
```